# Do listeners on futures consume memory in java?

Tags: java, event-listener

I am sending a ton of events and for each event I receive a future. I setup a completion listener on that future. 
What happens if I have too many futures listening for completion of events? Will my app run out of memory? 
When you add listeners in java, does it consume memory?

Comment: Please show code if possible.

Comment: Also, have you done any memory profiling?

Comment: An application with poorly written "listeners" can certainly cause memory leak. Consider reading about weak references.

Answer (score 1):

A Java Future is just a Java object, so yes, the Future consumes memory.

A bigger concern here is that this is a major opportunity for memory leaks. If you're not careful, you can accidentally hold on to references to objects for much longer than you intend (or even for the life of the application). Event handling is one of the primary causes of memory leaks in environments with managed memory.

It's really hard to tell if you'll run out of memory based on the information supplied, though. A few things to consider:

- Do the events cause you to "hold on" to memory-intensive objects for longer? If so, how much longer?
- How much is "a lot" in this case?
- How constrained is your memory in the first place?